# example using AndroidJsonfactory

Tags: android, json

I have develop an application that need nearest place.It uses google api for place search.
my question is how to develop a wrapper that abstarct our application and underlying webservice.
It uses features from library (google-http-client,google-http-client-android)

For Example :AndroidJsonParsor can use only android 3.0 version and above.We can use JsonHttpParser for compatibilty.

thanks in advace for your advice

Answer (score 0):

What you want actually, because google developers says Json support is added in API level 1. Means any Android Version will support Json.

Here is the link http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html